# How to get MediaFormat's csd-0 on android

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I get csd-0 by flowing code, but it always return null. How should I get it ?

```
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = mediaCodec.getOutputFormat().getByteBuffer("csd-0")
```

Comment: Did you started the decoder and executed this code line after getting a MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED ?

Comment: No, I dequeueOutputBuffer in a loop until get MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_CODEC_CONFIG